# Vaadin LoginForm - signaling when user passed or failed authentication

Tags: authentication, vaadin, event-listener, vaadin-flow

I understand that in using the [`Login`](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/) component of Vaadin 14, I must call [`addLoginListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/AbstractLogin.html#addLoginListener-com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener-) to register a listener of my own that implements `ComponentEventListener<AbstractLogin.LoginEvent>`. In my implementing code, I can call the [`LoginEvent::getUsername`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/AbstractLogin.LoginEvent.html#getUsername--) and [`LoginEvent::getPassword`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/AbstractLogin.LoginEvent.html#getPassword--) methods to obtain the text values entered by the user. My listener code then determines if these credentials are correct.

➥ By what mechanism does my listener code communicate back to my [`LoginForm`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginForm.html) the results of the authentication check?

If the authentication check succeeded, I need my `LoginForm` to close and let navigation continue on to the intended route. If the authentication failed, I need the `LoginForm` to inform the user about the failure, and ask user to re-enter username and password. How can my listener code tell the LoginForm what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `LoginForm` supports events only for its buttons

The `LoginForm` can register listeners for two kinds of events:

- User clicking the **"Log in" button**
- User clicking the **"Forgot Password" button**
  (which may or may not be displayed)

Neither of those is useful for us in detecting if the user successfully completed their login attempt. Whatever method that does register for the "Log in" button click will be deciding the user's success or failure. It is *that* method which needs to signal the successful login attempt.

As a [`Component`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.2/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html), the [`LoginForm`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.2/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginForm.html) has built-in support for [registering listeners](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.2/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html#addListener-java.lang.Class-com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener-) for other types of events. Unfortunately, that support has its scope restricted to `protected`. So that [event-listener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) support cannot extend to our web-app classes, as they are not part of the Vaadin packages (out of scope).

## Not using Routing

I tried and failed to use the Routing feature of Vaadin Flow. There seem to be some serious issues with routing behavior in Vaadin 14.0.2. Add on my ignorance of Routing, and it became a no-go for me. Instead, I am managing all the content from within my `MainView` using a single URL (root "").

## Subclass `LoginForm`

I do not know if this is the best approach, but I chose to make a subclass of `LoginForm` called `AuthenticateView`.

➥ On that subclass I added a nested interface `AuthenticationPassedObserver` defining a single method `authenticationPassed`. This is my attempt at a callback, to inform my `MainView` of the success of the user's attempt to login. This is the specific solution to the Question of how to signal when the user passed authentication: **Make the calling layout implement an interface defined on the `LoginForm` subclass, with a single method to be called after the user succeeds in their login attempt.**

### Failure is not an option

Notice that we do not care about a failure. We simply leave the `LoginForm` subclass displayed as our `MainView` content for as long as it takes until the user either succeeds or closes the web browser window/tab, thereby terminating the session. If you are worried about hackers trying endlessly to login, you may want your subclass of `LoginForm` to keep track of repeated attempts and react accordingly. But the nature of a Vaadin web app makes such an attack less likely.

### Callback

Here is that nested interface for the synchronous [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

```
    interface AuthenticationPassedObserver
    {
        void authenticationPassed ( );
    }
```

In addition, I defined an interface `Authenticator` that does the work of deciding if the username & password credentials are valid.

```
package work.basil.ticktock.backend.auth;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface Authenticator
{
    public Optional <User> authenticate( String username , String password ) ;

    public void rememberUser ( User user );  // Collecting.
    public void forgetUser (  );  // Dropping user, if any, terminating their status as  authenticated.
    public boolean userIsAuthenticated () ;  // Retrieving.
    public Optional<User> fetchUser () ;  // Retrieving.

}
```

For now I have an abstract implementation of that interface to handle the chore of storing an object of the `User` class I defined to represent each individual's login.

```
package work.basil.ticktock.backend.auth;

import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

public abstract class AuthenticatorAbstract implements Authenticator
{
    @Override
    public void rememberUser ( User user ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( user );
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute( User.class, user  ) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void forgetUser() {
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute( User.class, null  ) ; // Passing NULL clears the stored value.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userIsAuthenticated ( )
    {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = this.fetchUser();
        return optionalUser.isPresent() ;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional <User> fetchUser ()
    {

        Object value = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute( User.class ); // Lookup into key-value store.
        return Optional.ofNullable( ( User ) value );
    }

}
```

Perhaps I will move those methods to be `default` on the interface. But good enough for now.

I wrote some implementations. A couple were for initial design: one that always accepts the credentials without examination, and another that always rejects the credentials without examination. Another implementation is the real one, doing a look up in a database of users.

The authenticator returns an `Optional< User >`, meaning the optional is empty if the credentials failed, and containing a `User` object if the credentials passed.

Here is always-flunks:

```
package work.basil.ticktock.backend.auth;

import work.basil.ticktock.ui.AuthenticateView;

import java.util.Optional;

final public class AuthenticatorAlwaysFlunks  extends AuthenticatorAbstract
{
    public Optional <User> authenticate( String username , String password ) {
        User user = null ;
        return Optional.ofNullable ( user  );
    }
}
```

…and always passes:

```
package work.basil.ticktock.backend.auth;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

public class AuthenticatorAlwaysPasses extends AuthenticatorAbstract
{
    public Optional <User> authenticate( String username , String password ) {
        User user = new User( UUID.randomUUID() , "username", "Bo" , "Gus");
        this.rememberUser( user );
        return Optional.ofNullable ( user  );
    }
}
```

By the way, I am not trying to be fancy here with my use of a callback. A couple pressure-points led me to this design.

- I *did* want to keep the `LoginView` subclass ignorant of who is calling it. For one thing, I might some day get routing working, or implement some navigator framework, and then the larger context of who is display the `LoginForm` subclass may change. So I did *not* want to hardcode a call to method back on the `MainView` object that spawned this `LoginForm` subclass object.
- I would have preferred to the simpler approach of passing a method reference to the constructor of my `LoginForm` subclass. Then I could omit the entire define-a-nested-interface thing. Something like this: `AuthenticateView authView = new AuthenticateView( this::authenticationPassed , authenticator );`. But I am not savvy enough with [lambdas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) to know how to define my own method-reference argument.

## `MainView` - a controller for displaying and responding to `LoginView` subclass

Lastly, here is my early experimental attempt at modifying the `MainView` class given to me by the Vaadin Starter project.

Notice how `MainView` implements the nested callback interface `AuthenticateView.AuthenticationPassedObserver`. When the user successfully completes a login, the `authenticationPassed` method here on `MainView` is invoked. That method clears the `LoginForm` subclass from content display of `MainView`, and installs the regular app content for which the current user is authorized to view.

Also note the annotations:

- The `@PreserveOnRefresh` new to Vaadin Flow in version 14 keeps content alive despite the user clicking the browser Refresh button. That may help with the login process, thought I've not thought it through.
- Also, note the `@PWA`. I do not currently need the progressive web app features. But removing that annotation in a Vaadin 14.0.2 seems to cause even more spurious replacements of the `UI` object that contains our web browser window/tab contents, so I am leaving that line in place.
- While I am not making use of the Routing feature in Flow, I do not know how to disable that feature. So I leave the `@Route ( "" )` in place.

---

```
package work.basil.ticktock.ui;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.FlexComponent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PreserveOnRefresh;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import work.basil.ticktock.backend.auth.Authenticator;
import work.basil.ticktock.backend.auth.AuthenticatorAlwaysPasses;

import java.time.Instant;

/**
 * The main view of the web app.
 */
@PageTitle ( "TickTock" )
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements AuthenticateView.AuthenticationPassedObserver
{

    // Constructor
    public MainView ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "BASIL - MainView constructor. " + Instant.now() );
        this.display();
    }

    protected void display ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "BASIL - MainView::display. " + Instant.now() );
        this.removeAll();

        // If user is authenticated already, display initial view.
        Authenticator authenticator = new AuthenticatorAlwaysPasses();
        if ( authenticator.userIsAuthenticated() )
        {
            this.displayContentPanel();
        } else
        { // Else user is not yet authenticated, so prompt user for login.
            this.displayAuthenticatePanel(authenticator);
        }
    }

    private void displayContentPanel ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "BASIL - MainView::displayContentPanel. " + Instant.now() );
        // Widgets.
        ChronListingView view = new ChronListingView();

        // Arrange.
        this.removeAll();
        this.add( view );
    }

    private void displayAuthenticatePanel ( Authenticator authenticator )
    {
        System.out.println( "BASIL - MainView::displayAuthenticatePanel. " + Instant.now() );
        // Widgets
        AuthenticateView authView = new AuthenticateView(this, authenticator);

        // Arrange.
//        this.getStyle().set( "border" , "6px dotted DarkOrange" );  // DEBUG - Visually display the  bounds of this layout.
        this.getStyle().set( "background-color" , "LightSteelBlue" );
        this.setSizeFull();
        this.setJustifyContentMode( FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.CENTER ); // Put content in the middle horizontally.
        this.setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment( FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER ); // Put content in the middle vertically.

        this.removeAll();
        this.add( authView );
    }

    // Implements AuthenticateView.AuthenticationPassedObserver
    @Override
    public void authenticationPassed ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "BASIL - MainView::authenticationPassed. " + Instant.now() );
        this.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered, but I came across a similar problem with Vaadin 14.8.1 and found no answer. So I thought i might aswell describe the solution to it here.

In my case I wanted to intercept a successfull login for monitoring purposes. Basically I was looking for a event that is fired once a user is logged in and log the username.

The LoginForm from Vaadin doesn't provide any callbacks for this matter as described by the previous answer. Since Vaadin 14 uses Spring Boot and thus Spring Security, you can use it's functionality to implement a listener for successfull logins.

For this to work you need to create a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```java
public class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginSuccessHandler.class);
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Redirect to root page after login
        httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        LOGGER.info("User successfully logged in: {}", authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

Here you need to override the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method.
In the `Authentication` object you can find the username, password and authority(role) of the logged in user.

Important to note is that if you don't redirect the request, you will be stuck in the login screen. You can redirect to every route since the user is logged in and the session is created, but I'd advice to use the root route.

Now you need to add your handler to the SecurityConfig:

```java
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // Vaadin handles CSRF internally
    http.csrf().disable()

        // Register our CustomRequestCache, which saves unauthorized access attempts, so the user is redirected after login.
        .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())

        // Restrict access to our application.
        .and().authorizeRequests()

        // Allow all Vaadin internal requests.
        .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()

        // Allow all requests by logged-in users.
        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        // Configure the login page.
        .and().formLogin()
            .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
            .loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
            .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)
        // Configure logout
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
  }
```

Here you only need to set `.successHandler` property from the `.formLogin` configuration.

Now you should be able to intercept a successfull login and, in my case, log the logged in user.

For failed login attempts it goes the same way.

Hope this helps.