# How to define a instance-method-reference as an argument/parameter

Tags: java, lambda, arguments, parameter-passing, method-reference

Imagine a case where a `Person` object asks a `Scheduler` object to book an appointment, by invoking `bookAppointment` method. But an appointment is not available now. Later, when an appointment opens up, an appointment will be booked – and then the `Person` object wants to be notified. To be notified, we want a particular method `appointmentHasBeenBooked` to be invoked as a callback.

To keep it simple, let’s say we have no arguments to pass, and no return value for this `appointmentHasBeenBooked` method on `Person`.

```
public class Person { 

    // Callback - To be invoked after the `Scheduler` object succeeds in booking an appointment. 
    public void appointmentHasBeenBooked() {
        …
    }

}
```

Amidst the code of a method `fooBar` on the `Person` class, we establish a `Scheduler` object. Ideally, I would be able to pass a simple method reference for the callback from that method. Here is how I imagine that `foorBar` method, as it passes `this::appointmentHasBeenBooked` method-reference.

```
public class Person { 

    public void fooBar() {
        Scheduler scheduler = … ;
        scheduler.bookAppointment( this.id , this:: appointmentHasBeenBooked ) ;  // Asking the scheduler to eventually book an appointment for this person, and when accomplished, notify this person by invoking the passed method.
        …
    }

    // Callback - To be invoked after the `Scheduler` object succeeds in booking an appointment. 
    public void appointmentHasBeenBooked() {
        …
    }

}
```

Is this possible? I have not defined an interface, much less a [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

➥ If this is possible, how do I define the argument/parameter on `Scheduler` method `bookHasBeenAppointment` as a method reference?

And how does the method receiving the method-reference invoke that method?

```
public class Scheduler {
    public void bookAppointment( UUID id , methRef ) {
        … book the appointment
        invoke_methRef ;
    }
}
```

In that code above, what do I put for:

- `methRef`
- `invoke_methRef`

I have see many examples of *passing* a method references, such as `this::toString`. But I have not seen any explanation of defining the receiving end of a method-reference being passed.

I know the longer roundabout way to accomplish my goal: Define an interface `AppointmentBookingObserver` with a single method `appointmentBooked()`. Nest that interface on the `Scheduler` class. Declare `Person` as `implements Scheduler. AppointmentBookingObserver`. Then define the 2nd argument on `bookAppointment` as a `AppointmentBookingObserver` object. The `bookAppointment` method would eventually invoke the single interface method: `observer.appointmentHasBeenBooked`. This works, but seems overkill for such a simple single callback scenario. Just passing `this::appointmentHasBeenBooked` would be *so* much simpler and clearer.

No threads involved here. So need for Executors, `Runnable`, or concerns over thread-safety.

If you would rather have details of my actual use-case scenario instead of this contrived Person-Scheduler example above, see my other Question, [*Vaadin LoginForm - signaling when user passed or failed authentication*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57585303/642706).

Answer (score 3):

The method reference you are thinking can simply be a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) type

```
class Scheduler {

  public void bookAppointment( UUID id, Runnable callback) {
    // book appointment
    callback.run();
  }
}

class Person {

  public void appointmentBooked() {
    // some code
  }
}
```

and then

```
Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
Person person = new Person();

scheduler.bookAppointment( person.id , person::appointmentBooked);
```

Comment: No threading involved in my Question, so no need for `Runnable`.

Comment: @Basil there is no multi-threading involved. Runnable is just a functional interface here.

Comment: Ahhhh, I think I see, just use `Runnable` as a conveniently pre-defined functional interface rather than write my own nested interface. So simple. I will have to ponder that. Thanks!

Comment: @Basil yes that is the easiest and closest match for your need. See other options here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Comment: I have stared many times at [that page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). None of those seemed to fit the simple case of calling a no-arg method with no return-value. But `Runnable` is just that. My only concern that someone reading my code, and seeing a `Runnable`, will think threading is at hand. Is there some other interface, on that page or elsewhere, that would work? I suppose I could invent my own to use across my code base. But this seems like a common need for many people.

Comment: In your example code, shouldn't there be someplace where `run` method is implemented? And shouldn't something be declared as implementing `Runnable`?

Comment: @Basil ```person::appointmentBooked``` is equivalent to `new Runnable(){ @Override public void run() {person.appointmentBooked(); }}```

Answer (score 2):

It has been acknowledged in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27973294/2711488) that the reason for not adding another functional interface for a parameterless `void` operation was that `Runnable` does already fulfill the purpose.

So you may use

```
public class Scheduler {
    public void bookAppointment(UUID id, Runnable methRef) {
        … book the appointment
        methRef.run();
    }
}
```

to be invoked as

```
public class Person { 
    public void fooBar() {
        Scheduler scheduler = … ;
        scheduler.bookAppointment(this.id, this::appointmentBooked) ;  // Asking the scheduler to eventually book an appointment for this person, and when accomplished, notify this person by invoking the passed method.
        …
    }
    // Callback - To be invoked after the `Scheduler` object succeeds in booking an appointment. 
    public void appointmentBooked() {
        …
    }
}
```

But there’s an alternative

```
public class Scheduler {
    public <T> void bookAppointment(UUID id, T instance, Consumer<T> methRef) {
        … book the appointment
        methRef.accept(instance);
    }
}
```

to be invoked as

```
public class Person { 
    public void fooBar() {
        Scheduler scheduler = … ;
        scheduler.bookAppointment(this.id, this, Person::appointmentBooked) ;  // Asking the scheduler to eventually book an appointment for this person, and when accomplished, notify this person by invoking the passed method.
        …
    }
    // Callback - To be invoked after the `Scheduler` object succeeds in booking an appointment. 
    public void appointmentBooked() {
        …
    }
}
```

This emphases the “instance-method-reference” aspect of your question, though this construct does not enforce that the `Consumer` is such a method reference, but makes using such a method reference easier.

As a bonus, `Person::appointmentBooked` is a non-capturing method reference that gets evaluated to a `Consumer` instance which is reused on subsequent invocations.